# Issue with IQueryable<object> and List<string>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How to convert Object to List.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this issue.

This is the Error I am getting.

Comment: As a note the line `query2.Where(x => x.ba_Object_id != baObjectID);` doesn't look to do anything. `Where` doesn't change the original object, it just returns a new one which you are not using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480399/convert-listof-object-to-listof-string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your list is a `List<string>`, but your query returns a collection of `baObject`.  You need to either use `ToString()` on this, or change your query to return a specific member.

The first option would look like:

```
descList.AddRange(query2.Select(ba => ba.ToString()).ToList());
```

The second (more likely option) could be as simple as:

```
descList.AddRange(query2.Select(ba => ba.Name).ToList());
```

(This is assuming `baObject.Name` is the property you want to list.)