# Getting all elements from an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IEnumerable` called day.  I am trying to get all the elements from the `IEnumerable` and convert them to a string.  Using

```
string day = day.First().ToString()
```

I am able to get the first element.  I have tried using `.ToList()` and `.ToArray()` both do not print out the elements.

Comment: The answer of this question is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480399/convert-listof-object-to-listof-string).

Comment: @Aaron I believe you'll find what you need in the linked duplicate question, if not let me know and we can re-open this one and help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need linq for this, you can try this:

```
var days = new List<int> {1,2,3};
var result = String.Join(" ", days);//Out: 1 2 3
```