# List of values to list of strings

Tags: c#

How to convert it:

```
var values = new List<object> { 1, 5, "eeE", MyEnum.Value };
```

To

```
var stringValues = new List<object> { "1", "5", "eeE", MyEnum.Value.ToString() };
```

But do it in fast way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert List(of object) to List(of string)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480399/convert-listof-object-to-listof-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's not clear whether your question is any different from [Convert List(of object) to List(of string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480399/convert-listof-object-to-listof-string); if it is, you should clarify your particular situation.

The straight-forward solution is to use LINQ: `var stringValues = values.Select(v => (object) v.ToString()).ToList();`  Note the cast to `object` to match your code above.

It's not clear why you'd want your result to be `List<object>` instead of `List<string>`.  Also, you should prefer to work with `IEnumerable<>` instead of converting to a `List<>`.  So the **preferred** code would be

```
var stringValues = values.Select(v => v.ToString());
```

If you're doing this type of thing a lot, you might find an extension method useful

```
static class ListExtensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<string> AsStrings(this List<object> values)
   {
      return values.Select(v => v.ToString());
   }
}
```

You would use it like:

```
var stringValues = values.AsStrings();
```

Depending on your needs, you may want more a more sophisticated string conversion than `Object.ToString()`.  [`Convert.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh(v=vs.110).aspx) tries to first find [`IConvertable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`IFormattable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) interfaces before calling `ToString()`.

```
    var stringValues = values.Select(v => Convert.ToString(v));
```

Answer (score 2):

here's one approach

```
//original list
var values = new List<object> { 1, 5, "eeE", Colors.Red };
//List<string>
var stringValues = values.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
//List<object>
var stringValuesAsObjectList = values.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList<object>();
```

Comment: you're right. In that case, i have edited my answer.

Comment: @Ðаn - Most likely the OP does not know what they actually want/need or did not express their actual intent correctly.

Comment: @Igor I'm guessing you're right, but I have edited my answer for nitpickers and downvoters :)